# Docker containers random "Connection refused"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

We have a docker-swarm with a series of docker containers deployed all in the same network.

For some reason, sometimes, in a very punctual way, the communication between containers fails showing errors like:

> org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to app_name:
>   8080 [app_target / 10.0.0.3] failed : Connection refused (Connection
>   refused)

We deploy containers on the swarm using a docker-compose.yml like following

```
  app_origin:  
    image: app_origin:2.0.1
    deploy:
        resources:
            limits:
                memory: 768M
    environment:
        _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx768m -Xms256m
        APP_TARGET_URL: http://app_target:8080/
        JHIPSTER_SLEEP: '10'
        SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI: http://admin:pass@jhipster-registry:8761/config
        constraint: custom.layer==backend
    volumes:
    - /datos/logs/app_origin:/var/log:rw        
  app_target:  
    image: sd_buho:4.0
    deploy:
        resources:
            limits:
                memory: 1536M
    environment:
        _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx1536m -Xms256m
        JHIPSTER_SLEEP: '10'
        constraint: custom.layer==backend
    volumes:
    - /datos/app_target_data:/tmp:rw
```

When I connect to one of the containers to test ping to the other, it allways works.

```
queres@cgldoc-pre:~/01.04.00/docker-compose$ sudo docker exec -it c89fd05a1cda /bin/sh

$ ping app_target
PING app_target (10.0.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 10.0.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.093 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.072 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.3: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.096 ms
```

Has anyone had similar problems? any track is appreciated

Thanks in advance